Install qt6 in CLion with vcpkg
I'm new to CLion and vcpkg and started using it, because I want to use CGAL for my studies. I managed to install Qt5 with vcpkg by running C:\dev\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe install qt5.
With that I can run some of the demos from CGAL see CGAL-5.6.1-examples.zip
. But I can only run demos using Qt5 and not Qt6. For example, the "Hyperbolic_triangulation_2" requieres Qt6. My problem is, that I don't know how to install Qt6 with vcpkg.
It seems that Qt6 isn't available all vcpkg packages. I already downloaded Qt6 (the msvc version), but I don't know how to pass this to vcpkg. Probably I could also specify it in the CMakeLists.txt file, but for that an instruction would be nice. This is the CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12...3.29)
project(Hyperbolic_triangulation_2_Demo)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(CGAL REQUIRED OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS Core Qt6)
find_package(LEDA QUIET)

# Find Qt6 itself
find_package(Qt6 QUIET COMPONENTS Widgets)

if(CGAL_Qt6_FOUND
        AND Qt6_FOUND
        AND (CGAL_Core_FOUND OR LEDA_FOUND))

    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

    qt_add_executable ( HDT2 HDT2.cpp HDT2.ui resources/Delaunay_triangulation_2.qrc
            include/internal/Qt/HyperbolicPainterOstreamCK.h
            include/internal/Qt/TriangulationGraphicsItemWithColorInfo.h
            include/internal/Qt/TriangulationMovingPoint.h
            include/internal/Qt/TriangulationRemoveVertex.h)
    target_include_directories(HDT2 PRIVATE ./ ./include)
    add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS HDT2 )
    target_link_libraries ( HDT2 PRIVATE CGAL::CGAL CGAL::CGAL_Qt6 Qt6::Widgets)
    if(CGAL_Core_FOUND)
        target_link_libraries ( HDT2 PRIVATE CGAL::CGAL_Core)
    else()
        target_link_libraries ( HDT2 PRIVATE ${LEDA_LIBRARIES})
    endif()

    include(${CGAL_MODULES_DIR}/CGAL_add_test.cmake)
    cgal_add_compilation_test( HDT2 )
else()
    message("NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL_Core (or LEDA), and Qt6 and will not be compiled.")
endif()

How can I modify this CMakeLists.txt file to find Qt6. Qt6 is installed at C:\Qt\6.7.2\msvc2019_64

In vcpkg, it is called qt, not qt6, but the version is 6.*.
